# Running spork I get the error: Address already in use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spork

I'm assuming it was because the process didn't close properly and so is still running.  But using top or ps I can't find it.  Is there a way to find where it's running, or to have it force reopen the port?

Comment: I'm still having this problem - how did you resolve it?

Comment: the comment below answered it.  Run lsof -i | grep LISTEN, find the process running and kill it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `sudo netstat -lpn` to see what ports are being listened to, and what processes are listening.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  And when I run netstat I don't see any ports listed.

Comment: sorry, that's a Linux command. What OS are you on? On OS X you can do something similar with `lsof -i | grep LISTEN`

Answer (score 2):

In the case of an old instance of Spork running you may use this command:

```
pkill -f spork
```