# Running Spork for rails on linux using Virtual Box - Port in use error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, rspec, spork

On Ubuntu 11.0.4 and Fedora: 
I'm getting a "Address already in use - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)" error while using spork.

If I load spork using a different port, then rspec no longer detects a drb server - guard doesn't work with it either. I've tried installing a different OS, as well as using VMWare, and I get the same error.

How do I proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157978/running-spork-i-get-the-error-address-already-in-use/6158137#6158137

Comment: @Gustavo, thanks! I tried that already, but my problem with that one is I don't know which ports spork is trying to use - it doesn't show me. I tried some expected ports (8989 and one other), but those seem to be free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using a non-default port for the DRb server you can tell RSpec to use that alternate port by adding --drb-port [PORT] to your rspec call.

```
spork -p 5555
rspec spec --drb --drb-port 5555
```

Of course you can put all the rspec options into your .rspec file, then just remember to run that port when you fire up spork.

Comment: Thanks Cluster! When I do this, rspec just hangs - as in, it doesn't do anything, but is just stuck. When I exit spork, it resumes functionality after saying that no drb server was detected. It did the same thing when I run spork with a custom port (spork -p 5555), but without specifying a port for rspec. Any thoughts on how to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm - when I used the exact port you specified (5555), it seems to work. I put it in the .rspec file, and it's also working with autotest and guard. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

maybe there is another spork working.
look up the procedure list

Comment: I checked, and no - I first had the problem with xubuntu, so after multiple attempts i installed the default version of ubuntu - still the same thing.

Comment: whether the port:2 is bind by other programs. check the ports used.

Comment: how do I do that? if I do sudo netstat -lpn | grep 2, none of the ones listed with an ip have just :2 on them (for example 127.0.0.1:631).